# Find all values in column B that correspond to particular values in column A ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |
| a2 | b1 |
| a3 | b2 |
| a4 | b2 |
| a5 | b2 |
| a6 | b3 |

In a SQL table like above, I want to write a query to get me the following result

b1: a1,a2
b2: a3,a4,a5
b3: a6

assume all the values are varchar

Answer (score 1):

The [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT   b, LISTAGG(a, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY b
```

Answer (score 0):

Principally, the data should be grouped by the column `B`, and the concatenation should be applied to the column `A`.

1. If version of DB is ***11gR2+***, then the `LISTAGG()` function might be
   applied :

   ```
   SELECT B, 
          LISTAGG(A, ',') WITHIN GROUP 
          ( ORDER BY TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_REPLACE(A,'[^0-9]')) ) AS "Concatenated String"
     FROM tab
    GROUP BY B
    ORDER BY B
   ```
2. If version of DB is ***11gR2-***, then the `XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT())`
   function combination might be applied :

   ```
   SELECT B,
          RTRIM(DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
                  XMLAGG( 
                         XMLELEMENT(e,A||',')
                        ).EXTRACT('//text()').GETCLOBVAL() ,1),
                 ',') AS "Concatenated String"
     FROM tab
    GROUP BY B
    ORDER BY B
   ```

- ***Special Case*** If ***ORA-01489:** result of string concatenation is too long* , which raises whenever the concatenated string within the first argument exceeds the length of *4000* characters, occured :

  The above ***2nd case*** is applied. If the version of DB is ***12gR2+***, then the ***1st case*** might be used as

  ```
  SELECT B, 
         LISTAGG(A, ',' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE 'THE REST IS TRUNCATED' WITHOUT COUNT ) 
         WITHIN GROUP 
         ( ORDER BY TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_REPLACE(A,'[^0-9]')) ) AS "Concatenated String"
    FROM tab
   GROUP BY B
   ORDER BY B
  ```

  in order to truncate the trailing part without getting the error *ORA-01489* is raised.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=96073138e5a83fb8b105faea9d815481)</kbd>